# Gmail Email Markup not being called

Tags: html, email, gmail, google-schemas

I am trying to get the Email Markup working but while I have it in the code, it is not adding anything to my calendar. The HTML code passes the email markup tester ( https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/ ) and I am having our website send the emails as me to myself as it states in the Self testing ( https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema ). Is there any other way to debug this or figure out why it is not be triggered?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
    <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="2072913"/>
    <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/Confirmed"/>
    <div itemprop="bookingAgent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="StubWire.com"/>
        <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.stubwire.com"/>
        <meta itemprop="image" content="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/logo2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Brad Wickwire"/>
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="numSeats" content="10">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="0.00">
    <meta itemprop="bookingTime" content="2019-04-16T13:31:29-05:00"/>
    <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2019-04-16T16:51:31-05:00"/>
    <meta itemprop="modifyReservationUrl" content="https://www.stubwire.com/account/order.php?order=2072913"/>
    <meta itemprop="ticketDownloadUrl" content="https://www.stubwire.com/account/pop-print-tickets.php?order=2072913"/>
    <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Testing Scanner"/>
        <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2019-04-30T22:00:00-05:00">
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Tyndall Armory"/>
            <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.stubwire.com/t/ybz3pxmc"/>
            <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Indianapolis"/>
                <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="IN"/>
                <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="46204"/>
                <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="711 N. Pennsylvania St."/>
                <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="USA"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="act 1"/>
        <meta itemprop="image" content="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/events/original/19580-1ebca2d004ca628c07ed77154a7fb2c6.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="act 2"/>
        <meta itemprop="image" content="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/events/original/19681-ec14bd31f1ca83edc06d58da853766fc.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is our full HTML of the testing email

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="StubWire.com Email">
<title>Order Confirmation</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body, td {
    font-size:9pt;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
        <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="2072913"/>
        <link itemprop="reservationStatus" href="http://schema.org/Confirmed"/>
        <div itemprop="bookingAgent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="StubWire.com"/>
            <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.stubwire.com"/>
            <meta itemprop="image" content="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/logo2.png"/>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Brad Wickwire"/>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="numSeats" content="10">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="0.00">
        <meta itemprop="bookingTime" content="2019-04-16T13:31:29-05:00"/>
        <meta itemprop="modifiedTime" content="2019-04-16T16:51:31-05:00"/>
        <meta itemprop="modifyReservationUrl" content="https://www.stubwire.com/account/order.php?order=2072913"/>
        <meta itemprop="ticketDownloadUrl" content="https://www.stubwire.com/account/pop-print-tickets.php?order=2072913"/>
        <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MusicEvent">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Testing Scanner"/>
            <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2019-04-30T22:00:00-05:00">
            <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Tyndall Armory"/>
                <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.stubwire.com/t/ybz3pxmc"/>
                <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Indianapolis"/>
                    <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="IN"/>
                    <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="46204"/>
                    <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="711 N. Pennsylvania St."/>
                    <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="USA"/>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="act 1"/>
            <meta itemprop="image" content="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/events/original/19580-1ebca2d004ca628c07ed77154a7fb2c6.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="performer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="act 2"/>
            <meta itemprop="image" content="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/events/original/19681-ec14bd31f1ca83edc06d58da853766fc.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- STUBWIRE.COM EMAIL HEADER START -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle" style="background:#F4F4F4;"><a href="http://www.stubwire.com"><img src="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/logo2.png" border="0" alt="StubWire Logo" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#bcbcbc;height:1px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        <table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">Order Confirmation</span></td>
                </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                                              <tr>
                <td><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">Order # 2072913</span></td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-style:italic;font-size:12;"><b>Testing Scanner</b></span></td>
                        </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-style:italic;font-size:12;"><b>Tyndall Armory</b></span></td>
                        </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-style:italic;font-size:12;">Indianapolis, IN</span></td>
                        </tr>
                                              <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
<!-- STUBWIRE.COM EMAIL HEADER END -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><span style="font-style:italic;font-size:16px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Order Total:</span> $0.00</span></td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/1022838614583266/"><img src="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/rsvp_on_facebook.png" width="150" height="63" border="0" /></a>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
                        <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
                <table style="border:1px solid #06CDFF;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;background:#C1F2FF;padding:10px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%" valign="top" align="left">
                      Your tickets are attached to this email. Please open the PDF File and hit print which will print a sheet of paper for each ticket.
                                            <br><br>
                        <b>MOBILE FRIENDLY TICKETS:</b><br><a href="http://www.stubwire.com/t/55yius7l">http://www.stubwire.com/t/55yius7l</a><br>
                        <br>
                        <b>PRINT YOUR TICKETS:</b><br><a href="http://www.stubwire.com/t/9ihhbdeh">http://www.stubwire.com/t/9ihhbdeh</a>
                                        </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
      </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table style="border:1px solid #CDCFC0;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width:100%;background:#f7f7f7;padding:10px;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table style="width:100%;">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div style="font-size:18px;color:#DA2523;font-weight:bold;padding: 5px 0 5px 0;">Testing Scanner</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="width:50px;">
                    <img src="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/Image_Not_Available.gif" border="0" alt="Event Image">                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <div style="font-size:14px;color:#2e2e2e;font-weight:bold;">Tyndall Armory</div>
                    <div style="font-size:10px;color:#2e2e2e;">711 N. Pennsylvania St.</div>
                    <div style="font-size:10px;color:#2e2e2e;">Indianapolis, IN 46204</div>
                    <div style="font-size:12px;color:#2e2e2e;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Date:</span>
                                                                                                                            Tuesday April 30, 2019 10:00 PM
                                                                                                                        <br><span style="font-weight:bold;">Doors:</span> 9:00 PM
                                                                                                </div>
                </td>
                                <td align="right" valign="middle" style="width:160px;">
                                    <div style="margin-bottom:6px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stubwire.com%2Ft%2Fnfa4ngfx"><img src="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/btn_ShareFacebook.gif" width="150" height="28" alt="Facebook Share" /></a></div>
                                    <div><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Got+my+tix+to+Testing+Scanner+at+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stubwire.com%2Ft%2Fnhhg4bzj"><img src="https://stubwire-public.storage.googleapis.com/website/stubwire_v3/images/btn_ShareTwitter.gif" width="150" height="31" alt="Twitter Share" /></a></div>
                                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><span style="font-size:14px;color:#DA2523;font-weight:bold;">Ticket Details</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <table style="width:100%;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;background-color:#f7f7f7;font-size:12px;" cellpadding="5">
        <tr style="background-color:#CCCCCC;color:#DA2523;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;" cellpadding="5">
          <td>Ticket #</td>
          <td>Price Level</td>
          <td align="center" valign="top">Section</td>
          <td align="center" valign="top">Row</td>
          <td align="center" valign="top">Seat</td>
          <td align="center" valign="top">Face Value</td>
          <td align="center" valign="top">Service Fee</td>
        </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
              <td>733</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>734</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>735</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>736</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>737</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>738</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>739</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>740</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>741</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                                        <tr>
              <td>742</td>
                            <td>General Admission
                                                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">GA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">COMP</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">$0.00</td>
            </tr>
                                            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<!-- STUBWIRE.COM EMAIL FOOTER START -->
</td>
                </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>Thanks,</div>
                        <div>StubWire.com</div>
                        <div><a href="http://www.stubwire.com">http://www.stubwire.com</a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-size:12px;color:#DA2523;font-weight:bold;">*** DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL ***</span></td>
                </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>This email address is not monitored. Please goto <a href="http://www.stubwire.com/help/">http://www.stubwire.com/help/</a> if you have any questions about this email.</td>
          </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
  </tr>

</table>
<!-- Processed from web-instance-m00h by 99.23.88.85 ||PROCESSEDBY|| -->
<!-- STUBWIRE.COM EMAIL FOOTER END -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there any change if you use HTML 5?

Comment: I am not sure what I did but somehow I got it all to work. Thank you for trying to help though.